# Siunitx negative fractional power and \per

Tags: siunitx

Siunitx seems to typeset negative fractional powers differently depending on whether the `\per` command is used. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \SI{4}{\K\tothe{-4/3}}
    
    \SI{4}{\per\K\tothe{4/3}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a setting which controls this, or is it a bug in `siunitx`?

Comment: Bug report inquiries should be sent to the package's maintainer.

Comment: `\qty{4}{\per{\K\tothe{4/3}}}` works for me

Comment: @polyn I didn't know about `\qty`, thanks! However for me `\qty{4}{\per{\K\tothe{4/3}}}` behaves as though there is no `\per` (giving K^{4/3}). I just updated the package - perhaps this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

At present, I can offer an explanation only. The code to work out negative powers does multiplication of the exponent as an expression. That means that `-1 * (4/3)` is evaluated here, which comes out as `-1.333...`. On the other hand, a `\tothe` power used alone is just printed as-is.

Likely a change would need some form of 'pretty printing' for fractional powers, so I need to consider that before any adjustment.